# get the yaw angle between two frames

Tags: quaternion, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two frames, one is global frame, another is UAV frame. And i also have the transform between them.

how to get the yaw angle between global frame to UAV frame , So i can know the angle between global frame x_axis and  UAV framex_axis.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208347/get-the-yaw-angle-between-two-frames/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find it using `rotation matrix`.

get rotation matrix from transform. Each column in matrix represent unit vector along new axis. First column represent  unit vector of along new x-axis.

if m0, m1, m2 are elements of first column, angle between old and new x-axis is

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-05-02**:
thanks, it's right